# pgAdmin4 run vacuum error "'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, pgadmin-4

On one of my computers pgAdmin 4 always throws an error when I try selecting a table or database to vacuum.  But I have no problem running a query, or doing almost any other action within pgAdmin.

**Steps to reproduce**: Navigate to a database table, right click on the table, click on the menu item "maintenance", select any maintenance operation: "Vacuum" or "Analyse" or "Reindex" or "Cluster", click the "OK" button... then you'll see the error pop up at the bottom of the window in red.

- **Error message**: "'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"
- **PgAdmin 4 Versions tested**: 7.1, 7.2, 7.4 (all have the same error message)
- **Client OS**: Windows 11
- **Database**: AWS Aurora PgSql v14.7
- **Is Writer Instance**: Yes, I've verified I'm using the writer instance
- **Instance Type**: db.r6g.large
- **Time to error**: Immediately after clicking OK

Other notable troubleshooting information:

- I'm able to do this operation on my other computer with the same setup (pgAdmin 4 v 7.4, Windows Client, same database) and it works fine.
- If I try this same operation on another database I have, AWS RDS PgSql v15.3 (not Aurora), this operation via PgAdmin works fine.
- I've tried to uninstall PgAdmin and reinstall, but the same error appears.
- If I use dBeaver v23, I can vacuum a table in this database (the Aurora one) without a problem.

Comment: Not an answer, but why do you need to run vacuum? Autovacuum is turned on by default and does automatically what you try to do manually

Comment: @FrankHeikens thank you, although I'm aware of this.  Btw, this happens with all actions in that menu, "Vacuum" or "Analyse" or "Reindex" or "Cluster".

Comment: This looks like a python error. Do you have any python separately  installed?

Comment: Quoting the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html): *To vacuum a table, one must ordinarily be the table's owner or a superuser. However, database owners are allowed to vacuum all tables in their databases*. Are you table owner, database owner or superuser?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out... with a nudge from [jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721239/jjanes) it did look like a Python error and so I uninstalled Python from my machine (no restart required), I then tried the actions I described above and it works just fine now!  :D

It seems pgAdmin4 is written partially using [Python](https://www.pgadmin.org/development/#:%7E:text=pgAdmin%20is%20written%20in%20Python,afraid%20to%20get%20stuck%20in!) so I guess my installation of Python 3.x was conflicting with it somehow?  Hopefully this helps someone else out in the future.